# Connect oracle xe on ubuntu to sqldeveloper on mac

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-xe

I have a oracle xe databse server installed on ubuntu laptop. I am accessing the oracle database on my mac by doing ssh to the ubuntu laptop.

But now I have sqldeveloper installed on my mac and I want to connect to the database using the sqldeveloper but I am not able to do so.
Please guide me regarding this.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-may/o38sql-102034.html

Comment: @Joe I have few doubts. Do we need to have oracle client installed. If I directly make a new tnsnames.ora file in $HOME will it work. Is there any sample tnsnames.ora file, I can refer for connection?

Comment: Depends on how you want to connect. SQL Dev supports connecting with user, host, port and sid only = Basic Connection. When you create a connection, notice the "Connection Type" pulldown defaults to basic.

Answer (score 0):

You have a database running on a machine, A.

You have SQL Developer running on another machine, B.

If A can reach B, then that's good.

If B can 'talk' to A via the database listener port (1521 is the default), then that's awesome.

Let's cover this scenario first.

In SQL Developer, running on machine B, create a new connection.

[image]

You don't need to install an Oracle Client, you do not need a TNSNames.ora file. You can connect with the details of your database running on A.

Ok, now let's consider a scenario where you can reach A on the network, but ONLY port 22 is open.

Then you need to consider a SSH tunnel. You can set this up on your own, or you can do it with SQL Developer's built in SSH client and SSH connection features. You basically open a connection via SSH, and SQL Developer will piggy back on this connection and get to the database from the end of the tunnel - in your case, from machine A.

Example of [how to do a SSH Tunnel from SQL Developer here](https://dbaontap.com/2015/03/10/ssh-tunnel-with-sqldev-4-1-ea1-and-ea2-side-by-side/).